# Most efficient way to use navbars?

Tags: html

Very new to HTML/CSS. How should I go about making a navbar that is tracked globally across my pages? Like if I add an item to the list on the navbar, I'd like it to update across all pages instead of writing it in one page after another.

Comment: Are you building you site in straight html or are you using something like PHP?

Comment: @AI52487963 What server side language you are using , I think you are tlking about master page

Comment: I had been doing only html like a big dum dum. I only just assumed I'd run into some kind of optimization thing like this eventually. Never done anything with PHP before or server-side stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do that would be using a server side scripting language (like PHP). You cannot achieve that using only client side scripting (HTML and CSS).
Using PHP `include` you can add external files, like so:

```
<?php
include('filename.php');
?>
```

The file `filename.php` will be added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP:

```
<?php
include ('navbar.php');
?>
```

Create a navbar.php file with your html code in it.